# Mange users without permission package

Tags: laravel-backpack

How can I manage users without user the Backpage Permission package?

Basically all users will be the same level. I tried creating a User crud and tying to the original User model but that doesnt seem to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Walker. User is just another model, so you can create a CRUD for it like any other https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-example

Comment: Take inspiration from the PermissionMa ager package by browsing it on github.